# Finding the least common multiple (LCM) of a number in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have written the following code for finding lcm in python and am getting two answers with an example of 2, 8. How do I get it right without changing the logic?

```py
def lcm(a, b):
    if a >b:
        smaller = b
    else:
        smaller = a
    for i in range(smaller, (a*b)+1):
        while (i%a) == 0 and (i%b) == 0:
            print(i)
            break
    return 0

n, m = (int(x) for x in input('Enter the two numbers\t:').split())
lcm(n, m)
```

OUTPUT( for n = 2 and m = 8):

```
F:\Higher\venv\Scripts\python.exe F:/Higher/lcm.py
Enter the two numbers   :2 8
8
16

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Hi. Going ahead, Please try to keep the title brief and to the point. Add description of the question in the text and use code blocks for writing the code section.

Answer (score 0):

You're going into two loops by using while. and when you use break it gets you out of the while loop only and not the for loop above. Use an 'if' statement instead.

```
if a >b:
    smaller = b
else:
    smaller = a
for i in range(smaller, (a*b)+1):
    if((i%a) == 0 and (i%b) == 0):
        print(i)
        break
return 0
```

Your least common multiple is the first number that has modulus zero. you just print that and break.

Answer (score 0):

Since Lcm(a,b) * Hcf(a,b) = a*b (basic math learned in school)

LCM(a,b) = ab/HCF(a,b)

The code will look something like this:

```
import math
a = 13
b = 5
print((a*b)/math.gcd(a,b))
```

if you don't want to use math.gcd() then code will be:

```
def hcfnaive(a, b):
    if(b == 0):
        return abs(a)
    else:
        return hcfnaive(b, a % b)
a = 13
b = 5
print((a*b)/hcfnaive(a,b))
```